# static function declarations in header files

Tags: c, header-files, static-functions

I have a static function in a source file that is used by other functions in that same source file. Is it fine to put the declaration for that static function in the header file, even though that header file will be included into other source files? Example:

```
/* foo.c */
#include "foo.h"
 
/* exported function; calls g */ 
void f(void) {
    g(); 
}

static 
void g(void) {
    /* do something... */
}

/* foo.h */ 
void f(void); 
void g(void);


/* main.c */ 
#include "foo.h"

int main(void) {
   f();
}
```

Comment: Your code size will increase by that function size everytime it's included in a .c file. That's duplicated code isolated to each translation unit. If that's what you want it's fine but I dont see a good reason for that.

Comment: @BaileyKocin no the definition for that static function is only not in a header file, only in that source file.

Comment: Then you are just duplicating symbols. Which g are you actually using in foo.c? Is it the static one or global one. Who knows.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it fine to put the declaration for that static function in the header file, even though that header file will be included into other source files?

No.  Consider the conflict the other source files would have if they had a function/object/macro of the same name.

Even without conflict, an  "unused function" warning may occur. [@Adrian Mole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62841335/static-function-declarations-in-header-files/62841394#comment111127809_62841394)

By putting `static void g(void)` in the .h file, it adds an unnecessary potential name conflict.

---

Simply declare/define that static function at the top of the .c in which it is used.

Comment: what do you think would be a better approach

Comment: Even without such conflicts, you're likely to generate an "unused function" (or similar) warning for each source file that includes that header.

Comment: The better approach is to not include the declaration in the header file!

Comment: @topoly Post ameneded

Comment: @WilliamPursell so I should just keep the declaration in the source file?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it fine to put the declaration for that static function in the
> header file, even though that header file will be included into other
> source files?

No. becuse it does not make any sense. and why?
In `C`, functions are `global` by default. Unlike `global functions` in C, access to `static functions` is restricted to the file where they are declared! Therefore, when we want to `restrict access` to functions, we make them static.

Another reason for making functions static can be reuse of the same function name in other files. so declaring them static in the header file can cause to name collisons in other source files.

In header files we declare our API functions those we want to expose only. in c files we declare usually auxilary functions as static functions for restricting the scope of those aux functions to the c file only